# segfault in a C garbage collector

Tags: c, garbage-collection, segmentation-fault

I'm building a simple garbage collector in C, with a void pointer linked list that collects the malloced pointers and frees them all at the end.

```
#include "linked_list.h"

#define MAKE_GC(NAME) \
MAKE_LIST(NAME); \
static void _throw_away_##NAME() { \
    ITERATOR(NAME) = &NAME; \
    do { \
        free(ITERATOR(NAME)->elem); \
    } while ((ITERATOR(NAME) = ITERATOR(NAME)->next) != NULL); \
    DESTROY_LIST(NAME); \
}

#define GC_ALLOC(TYPE, TARGET, LEN, GC_NAME) \
do { \
    TARGET = (TYPE *)malloc(LEN * sizeof(TYPE)); \
    PUSH(TYPE *, TARGET, GC_NAME); \
} while (0)

#define GC_FREE(NAME) _throw_away_##NAME()
```

The above is the garbage collector, and below is linked_list.h

```
struct linked_list {
    void *elem;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

#define ITERATOR(LIST_NAME) _iter_##LIST_NAME

#define MAKE_LIST(NAME) \
struct linked_list NAME = { NULL, NULL }; \
struct linked_list *ITERATOR(NAME) = &NAME

#define PUSH(TYPE, X, LIST) \
do { \
    ITERATOR(LIST) = ITERATOR(LIST)->next = (struct linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list)); \
    *(TYPE *)ITERATOR(LIST)->elem = X; \
    ITERATOR(LIST)->next = NULL; \
} while (0)

#define DESTROY_LIST(LIST) \
do { \
    struct linked_list *l; \
    ITERATOR(LIST) = &LIST; \
    do { \
        l = ITERATOR(LIST)->next; \
        free(ITERATOR(LIST)); \
    } while ((ITERATOR(LIST) = l) != NULL); \
} while (0)
```

When I test this code with the following,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "garbage_collector.h"

MAKE_GC(char_gc);

int main() {
    char *str;
    int i;

    GC_ALLOC(char, str, 11, char_gc);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        putchar(str[i] = i + '0');
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    putchar('\n');
    puts(str);

    GC_FREE(char_gc);
    return 0;
}
```

It runs as expected, although the debuggers (gdb and Visual Studio debugger) keep on throwing segfaults in GC_ALLOC. It's a really short piece of code, and I'm quite annoyed that I still have no clue where it goes wrong.

I want to be sure where my program is broken and fix it before implementing elsewhere. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where do you include `stdlib.h`?  Why are you casting the return value of `malloc`?

Comment: stdlib.h should be included in the both header files, and that is not causing the problem for sure. I cast the malloc because I often compile with a c++ compiler, especially Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `PUSH` macro, I don't think this line is correct:

```
*(TYPE *)ITERATOR(LIST)->elem = X; \
```

I think you want something like this:

```
ITERATOR(LIST)->elem = (void *)X; \
```

In your code, I get a seg fault here:

```
GC_ALLOC(char, str, 11, char_gc);
```

and it's due to the fact that `GC_ALLOC` does a `PUSH`, passing `str` as X.  Once `str` has been properly allocated by the previous line, you want to assign the pointer to `elem`, but your code attempts to *dereference* `elem`, and then assign the pointer to that dereferenced item.  dereferencing `elem` is illegal at that point, and seg faults, because it has not been allocated (and should not be at that point).

After that, you have a problem at the final `GC_FREE` in your code, because it eventually tries to free an unallocated pointer.  When `GC_FREE` attempts to `DESTROY_LIST(gc_Char)`, it starts with the first item in the list.  But this item was not allocated via `malloc` (take a look at `MAKE_LIST`), so it cannot be free'd using `free`.  So we have to skip past this first item in the list when we want to `DESTROY_LIST`.  The following code has these items fixed and seems to work correctly for your test case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct linked_list {
    void *elem;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

#define ITERATOR(LIST_NAME) _iter_##LIST_NAME

#define MAKE_LIST(NAME) \
struct linked_list NAME = { NULL, NULL }; \
struct linked_list *ITERATOR(NAME) = &NAME

#define PUSH(TYPE, X, LIST) \
do { \
    ITERATOR(LIST) = ITERATOR(LIST)->next = (struct linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list)); \
    ITERATOR(LIST)->elem = (void *)X; \
    ITERATOR(LIST)->next = NULL; \
} while (0)

#define DESTROY_LIST(LIST) \
do { \
    struct linked_list *l; \
    ITERATOR(LIST) = &LIST; \
    l = ITERATOR(LIST)->next; \
    while ((ITERATOR(LIST) = l) != NULL) { \
        l = ITERATOR(LIST)->next; \
        free(ITERATOR(LIST)); \
    }  \
} while (0)

#define MAKE_GC(TYPE, NAME) \
MAKE_LIST(NAME); \
static void _throw_away_##NAME() { \
    ITERATOR(NAME) = &NAME; \
    do { \
        free(ITERATOR(NAME)->elem); \
    } while ((ITERATOR(NAME) = ITERATOR(NAME)->next) != NULL); \
    DESTROY_LIST(NAME); \
}

#define GC_ALLOC(TYPE, TARGET, LEN, GC_NAME) \
do { \
    TARGET = (TYPE *)malloc(LEN * sizeof(TYPE)); \
    PUSH(TYPE *, TARGET, GC_NAME); \
} while (0)

#define GC_FREE(NAME) _throw_away_##NAME()

MAKE_GC(char, char_gc);

int main() {
    char *str;
    int i;
    GC_ALLOC(char, str, 11, char_gc);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        putchar(str[i] = i + '0');
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    putchar('\n');
    puts(str);
    GC_FREE(char_gc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand why `*(TYPE *)ITERATOR(LIST)->elem = X;` is an incorrect line. It works without problem if `TYPE` is not a pointer but an `int` or `char` or whatever. Also, `DESTROY_LIST` works correct because `MAKE_LIST` always initializes the first element to `NULL`